# MYSQL Select tables starting with "x"

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a bunch of tables in my "stats" database.

```
tcl20151w1d1
tcl20151w1d2
tcl20151w2d1
tcl20151w2d2
tcl20151w3d1
tcl20151w3d2
tcl20151w4d1
eu20151w1d1
eu20151w1d2
eu20151w2d1
eu20151w2d2
eu20151w3d1
eu20151w3d2
eu20151w4d1
..
```

How can i select all tables that starts with "tcl" in "stats" database. Is it possible? Do I have to union them manually?

Comment: Use [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) or [LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like).

Comment: I assume you don't actually just want to select the table names, but some data from the tables?

Comment: @DigitalChris yes i want to get datas after select :)

Answer (score 1):

You can query [information_schema.tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tables-table.html) table to get a list of tables where the table name start with tcl.

You can use the list to dynamically create a union query in a stored procedure using string concatenation and [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

If those tables are all myisam tables with the same structure, you may consider creating a [merge table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/merge-storage-engine.html) on them:

> The MERGE storage engine, also known as the MRG_MyISAM engine, is a
>   collection of identical MyISAM tables that can be used as one.
>   “Identical” means that all tables have identical column and index
>   information.